# Different outputs when using file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I was trying to get the contents of the following URL using PHP's file_get_contents()
however the output is different than when using my browser. I tried setting a user-agent but that didn't work, I also tried completly simulating the HTTP request my browser did, but without luck. Does anyone an idea what can make it work? When using PHP I get to an login form
but when opening trough my browser it simply opens the schedules:

The URL is as following:

https://webuntis.a12.nl/WebUntis/Timetable.do?type=1

Comment: Are you sending cookies? How do you compare HTTP request from the browser with what PHP is doing?

Comment: I'm not sending any cookies. This shouldn't be needed because my browser doesn't send them either. I simply compare the the HTML output from PHP to the HTML in my browser (same url) but totally different outputs.

Comment: Are you sure there are no cookies? If you go to the other computer and load this url, will you get the login form? Are there any cookies set in the browser after you login?

Comment: Is the page you are looking for the login page, or something else?

Comment: The login page IS NOT what I'm looking for. I just saw trough the Google Chrome element inspector that there are some cookies. Should I create a stream context and set the exact same cookies ?

Comment: But when going trough the browser it does NOT show the login screen. And logging in should not be required. I now saw that the cookies change when I refresh the page, should I use Curl, request the page and then do a second request with the same curl object ?

Comment: When you call the login page, you actually get initially sent to a "security check" page, this then redirects you to a the actual login page. Are you following the same path? file_get_contents should follow redirect by default, but worth checking against fiddler or some other network profiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the URI you are attempting to access requires authentication. So you will need to implement that authentication procedure in PHP if you want PHP to be making the requests for you.

This can be done one of two ways. The first, is using [PHP's built in HTTP stream wrappers](http://php.net/context.http), which is pretty easy to work with, in my opinion. The other is to use [cURL](http://php.net/curl), which can be a bit of a swiss-army-knife of sorts. So you might get a bit overwhelmed, but both options should be fairly trivial on the surface.

What you need is to send a post request to the `action` attribute in the form on that page and then from the response you'll have to extract the cookie from the [$_COOKIE superglobal](http://php.net/%24_COOKIE) and send that along with every subsequent request. There are examples on in the manual that I linked to here.

Comment: I know how a login form works and I know I can simulate it by using a POST request. The problem here is that you DON't need to login. I can access the URL from any computer with any browser without seeing the login form. So there must be something.

Comment: I thought about doing a GET request with CURL and then doing a second request with CURL using the the same curl object or pass the cookies along.

Comment: When I visit on the URL you provided here I am directed to a login form. So I'm not sure why you believe that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, after checking everything out I found out that there were some cookies send by the server. After extracting them and supplying them with every request, it was fine.